# Why do people use ASC in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I've read a book about SQL and found that you can sort the data from columns in descending och ascending order.
But from my point of view, i dont understand why you would use order by ASC instead of just order by

Example:

```
SELECT state FROM country ORDER BY state;
SELECT state FROM country ORDER BY state ASC;
```

Why did they bother to implement ASC since just ordering by the column name brings the same result?

Comment: syntax error: `SELECT state FROM country ORDER BY ASC;` -->> `SELECT state FROM country ORDER BY state ASC;` (in other words: why do people ignore syntactic rules?)

Comment: @wildplasser You have made a mistake in your code:
` order by state ASC ` obviously gives syntax error.. 
You should read it again.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it helps to be overly verbose so that others can more easily/quickly understand your query.  For example, maybe you are writing a stored procedure with a decision structure such that one branch sorts ascending and the other descending.  By being explicit you can emphasize to the reader the difference between the two branches.

Just a thought.

Comment: Good point.  There's also symmetry to be considered.  If the syntax offers `DESC`, then it needs it's opposite, `ASC`, for symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Ommiting `ASC` is just a trick to reduce verbosity. Like ommiting `INNER` (from `INNER JOIN`) and so on.